# getting return value from confirm alert function so that i can setEditclicked to false

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, callback

i have a function confirm which asks for confirmation through react-confirm-alert. i need to get some reply back from this function if user clicks yes or no so that i can set editClicked to false. following is my code.

```
const handleClickUpdate = () => {
if (previousValue !== post)
  editPost(post, postId, "original")
    .then(() => setEditClicked(false))
    .catch(() => {
      confirm("edit", post, postId, editPost);
    });
 };




import { confirmAlert } from "react-confirm-alert";
export const confirm = (id, arg1, arg2, cb) => {
let title, message;

if (id === "delete") {
title = "Are you sure you want to delete this post";
message = "click yes to proceed";
} else {
title = "This post title already exists";
message = "Do you still want to continue";
}

confirmAlert({
title: title,
message: message,
buttons: [
  {
    label: "Yes",
    onClick: () => {
      id === "delete" ? cb(arg1, arg2) : cb(arg1, arg2, "duplicate");
    },
  },
  {
    label: "No",
    onClick: () => "no",
  },
],
});
};
```

---

**Edit:**

1. I need confirm function to return some value back, so that handle click update can set the state of edit clicked to true or false depending upon the click of the user. If user clicked yes, state would be false and vice versa
2. `onClick: () => "no"`, suppose if no is clicked, is there a way to return a value so that handle click update which is calling the confirm function would know that no was clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could pass a cancel callback to call and pass a value back out. Here I've called it `cb2` "callback 2".

```
const confirm = (id, arg1, arg2, cb, cb2) => {
  let title, message;

  if (id === "delete") {
    title = "Are you sure you want to delete this post";
    message = "click yes to proceed";
  } else {
    title = "This post title already exists";
    message = "Do you still want to continue";
  }

  confirmAlert({
    title: title,
    message: message,
    buttons: [
      {
        label: "Yes",
        onClick: () => {
          id === "delete" ? cb(arg1, arg2) : cb(arg1, arg2, "duplicate");
        }
      },
      {
        label: "No",
        onClick: () => cb2("no") // <-- pass cancel value back out.
      }
    ]
  });
};
```

Example usage:

```
<button
  type="button"
  onClick={() =>
    confirm(
      "test",
      0,
      1,
      (...args) => console.log("confirmed", args),
      (value) => console.log("declined", value)
    )
  }
>
  Open Confirm
</button>
```

A more specific example:

```
confirm("edit", post, postId, editPost, cancelEditPost);
```

[image: Edit getting-return-value-from-confirm-alert-function-so-that-i-can-seteditclicked-to]